# Custom Group and SUM Condition

Tags: mysql

I have a invoice journal table like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHQrc.jpg) And I want the result to look like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zuhzr.jpg) .What query should I use to retrieve the result like the example. I was trying to use group query and sum condition query but it still doesn't do what I want.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please show what you've tried.

Comment: SELECT SUM(IF(INVOICE AMOUNT >0,INVOICE AMOUNT, INVOICE AMOUNT)) AS INVOICE AMOUNT GROUP BY VENDOR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way would be to add the positive or negative to your group by.

```
SELECT VENDOR, SUM(INVOICEAMOUNT) AMTTOTAL
FROM FinTable
GROUP BY VENDOR, CASE WHEN INVOICEAMOUNT>= 0 THEN 'POS' ELSE 'NEG' end
```